# "Not only one of the most talented actors of our age but kind." -- what does 'kind' mean here?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, syntactic-analysis

I was searching for information about the original novel "House of Cards" and from following site, in the middile of the page, there's sentence which compliment Kevin Spicey as shown below(http://www.michaeldobbs.com/house-of-cards/):

> He's not only one of the most talented actors of our age but ***kind***,
>   too.

I don't think the "Kind" here means Spacey's a nice guy, I guess it might imply that he's a good actor of "man kind" (our kind)? I couldn't find any sentence with similar structure as an example to support my guess, so please anyone can explan to me the real meaning of the word "kind" here, better with some example, thanks.

Comment: Why do you dismiss the notion that the "kind" here means Spacey's a nice guy?

Comment: To clear the ambiguity, I like Spacey as an actor:).But in the context of this article the word "kind" is bit out of context for me if it means "nice guy", as the sentence mainly talking about him as a actor, regarding his performing skill, nothing to do with his characteristics.

Comment: The big problem is that this sentence is missing a comma before "but kind" which would make it more understandable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does mean that he's a nice guy.

Look at the context. The piece is on an author's website, and is talking about an adaptation of one of his books.

In the previous sentence, Spacey has paid the author a compliment with, "'this wouldn't have been possible without the brilliant material it was based on". Calling him "kind" is acknowledging that fact.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing my mind. I see, ok he is a nice guy:) I was just thinking too much during the last 30min regarding this sentence, need to grab a can of coke now:) --Cheers--